# How to get pedestrian number from Hikvision camera?

Tags: sdk, counting, ip-camera

I have a Hikvision IP Camera with built in people counting application. I am trying to build an desktop/web application, which read the number of people passed and process it. I just wanna know how can i catch the number of these people, no mater with what programming language. Camera model is Hikvision iDS-2CD6412FWD/C. Any answer matter. Thank you.

Comment: any progress on this trying to do the same thing

Comment: try this [http://yourIP/ISAPI/System/Video/inputs/channels/1/counting/search](http://yourIP/ISAPI/System/Video/inputs/channels/1/counting/search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the endpoint is:

```
/ISAPI/System/Video/inputs/channels/1/counting/search
```

and the xml body is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<countingStatisticsDescription xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <reportType>daily</reportType>
    <timeSpanList>
        <timeSpan>
           <startTime>2017-05-03T00:00:00</startTime>
            <endTime>2017-05-03T23:59:59</endTime>
        </timeSpan>
    </timeSpanList>
</countingStatisticsDescription>
```

Comment: I get "deviceError" with this, anyone had similiar problem?

Answer (score 0):

it works for url:

```
http://yourip:yourport/ISAPI/System/Video/inputs/channels/1/counting/search
```

and xml:

```
<CountingStatisticsDescription version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.isapi.org/ver20/XMLSchema">
  <statisticType>peoplePassing</statisticType>
  <reportType>daily</reportType>
  <timeSpanList>
    <timeSpan>
           <startTime>2024-01-01T00:00:00</startTime>
           <endTime>2024-01-01T23:59:59</endTime>
    </timeSpan>
  </timeSpanList>
  <MinTimeInterval>hour</MinTimeInterval>
</CountingStatisticsDescription>
```